# Custom Polygon Image Boolean Mask

Tags: python, image, masking

I am having trouble formulating a solution to a problem and I don't really know the right keywords to search for so I come here for some help.

I have an astronomy image that has stars mapped to the image, which is essentially saying I have some image with a set of points randomly spread out over the it with x and y pixel coordinates.  The only problem is some of these "stars" are just bad detections and our attempts to filter them out while also keeping good points as yielded lack luster results.  These points come from bad pixel columns or foreground stars that are saturating the imager.

I want to then be able to go into the image by hand an specify shapes bound by coordinates that will exclude any points from these areas.  For example, I have some big blown up diffraction spiking star that I want to put some kind of boxy star around it.  Another is some slanted bad column that I want to exclude so I want to put a rhombus around this and exclude all the bad points within it.

This is tantamount to me wanting to be able to form some kind of polygon mask given a set of connecting points, and be able to apply that to the image where it will then exclude those points within.

Just doing some brain storming and trying to find something on the internet, I had a thought of making some kind of custom polygon object that can be applied to all points which thus widdling down the bad points one shape at a time.

The only problem is I am having a hard time imagining how I would do this.  Is there any good resources or advice for implementing such a mask?  Elsewise, is there a better technique for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Numpy has masking features. But I don't think you'd even need them. You could just set portions of your image to zero, if I understand you right. If the field does not change you could do that programmatically. If the aperatures are square, you could even use `slicing` operations as in `aa[13:20, 33:40]=0` where `aa` is your array. If you want to do it interactively by clicking on pixels, look up custom event handlers (http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I had actually the same idea that it would be cool if I could do it interactively, but unfortunately I can't put in the time for something like that right now.  What maybe isn't clear enough is that my set of points has X, Y points corresponding to the image but other than that they are independent of each other.  I found a technique called point-in-polygon that gives me exactly what I need, and am at the time of writing this currently implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem called perfectly for something call point-in-polygon.  Some research I got a hold of an algorithm that essentially takes a simple polygon and finds the intersection with any edges to the right of the point.  If there is an even number of collisions then the point is outside of the polygon and  vice-versa for odd number of collisions; this is called the even-odd rule.  There are some limitations but with a high degree of accuracy in point positions it is very successful.

Here is a link to a useful source I found on the two most used algorithms in this problem space: [point-in-polygon](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html).

Here is the solution I ended up coming up with to apply the algorithm in Python (hope it might help others):

```
class Polygon():
"""
Make some polygon with edges and vertices.
"""
def __init__(self, points):
    """
    Takes in list of tuple points specifying each vertex.
    """

    ## Build polygon rith a list of edges
    self.edges = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        if(i < (len(points) - 1)):
            # construct with the vertices of i to len - 2
            vi = Vertex(points[i][0], points[i][1])
            vj = Vertex(points[i+1][0], points[i+1][1])
            e_current = Edge(vi, vj)
            self.edges.append(e_current)
        else:
            # construct last vertex that connects back to beginning
            vi = Vertex(points[i][0], points[i][1])
            vj = Vertex(points[0][0], points[0][1])
            e_current = Edge(vi, vj)
            self.edges.append(e_current)


def isInside(self, P):
    """
    Takes in a tuple P and sees if this point is inside the instance of polygon.
    """
    P = Vertex(P[0], P[1])
    collisions = 0
    for e in self.edges:
        if(((e.getStartPoint().y <= P.y) and (e.getEndPoint().y > P.y)) or ((e.getStartPoint().y > P.y) and (e.getEndPoint().y <= P.y))):
            vt = 1.0 * (P.y - e.getStartPoint().y) / (e.getEndPoint().y - e.getStartPoint().y)
            if(P.x < e.getStartPoint().x + vt * (e.getEndPoint().x - e.getStartPoint().x)):
                collisions += 1

    if collisions % 2 == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def getSize(self):
    return len(self.edges)


def toString(self):
    string = ""
    for e in self.edges:
        string += (e.toString() + "\n")
    return string

class Edge():
"""
Consruct an edge from two vertices vi, vj.
"""
def __init__(self, vi, vj):
    self.vi = vi
    self.vj = vj

def getStartPoint(self):
    return self.vi


def getEndPoint(self):
    return self.vj

def toString(self):
    return "Edge from " + self.vi.toString() + " to " + self.vj.toString() + "."

class Vertex():
"""
Construct a vertex out of x and y coordinates
"""
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def toString(self):
    return "(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"
```